# How to parallelize column loop in a 2d array in openmp

Tags: openmp

I am trying to parallelize column loop in the following code in openmp. But each thread prints the array individually.I just want to split column loop equally among the threads.

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
 {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
   {
   printf("arr[i][j]=%d",tid);
   }
  }

  My expected output is
   arr[1][1]=thread 0
   arr[1][2]=thread 1
   arr[1][3]=thread 2
   arr[1][4]=thread 3
   arr[1][5]=thread 0
   arr[2][1]=thread 0
    ......
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do.

Comment: I just want to parallelize j loop